# Como establecer un color de borde fijo a un v-text-field de vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Necesito que se vea exactamente así. Gracias a todos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo he logrado, con esto queda 100% solucionado.

```
   .v-text-field--outlined fieldset {
    border: solid 2px #214f6e !important;
    }
```